# shared memory, how to access from another cpp file

Tags: c++, shared-memory

What I have done so far:

### `main.cpp`

```
using namespace std;

bool *failOver = static_cast<bool*>(mmap(0,sizeof(failOver),
                                    PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE,
                                    MAP_SHARED|MAP_ANONYMOUS,-1,0));

int main()
{
   call of function from function.cpp.
}
```

### `function.cpp`

```
extern bool* failOver;

function test()
{
    //sem_wait(shared sem)
    modify failOver;

    //sem_post(shared sem)
}
```

If I try to compile it, it returns an error: "cannot convert `bool` to `bool*` in assignment". Also accessing with `std::failOver` does not work.

How do I access the shared memory variable from other files?

Comment: If you're having this kind of problem, it's a bit early for you to mess around with shared memory. Start at the beginning.

Comment: What is `modify failOver;`? And what line of code is associated with the conversion error? The code you pasted doresn't seem to relate to the question you asked in any way at all.

Comment: Why would you think it would possibly be defined within the `std` namespace unless you (disgustingly) put it there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In main.cpp it should be

```
bool *failOver = static_cast<bool*>(mmap(0,sizeof(*failOver),PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE,MAP_SHARED|MAP_ANONYMOUS,-1,0));
```

the size was wrong. In function.cpp

```
extern bool* failOver;

function test()
{
    //sem_wait(shared sem)
    *failOver = false;
    //sem_post(shared sem)
}
```

Is it as simple as you missing the `*` in `*failOver`? Reading Paolo latest answer he's come to the same conclusions.

Comment: Yes it as simple...im missing the *. Head -> Table. THANKS!

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing together a few different problems.

1- `bool* failOver` is not a `bool`, it is a pointer to `bool`; in other words, `failOver` represents the memory address where the `bool` you are interested in is stored. If you wanna read the `bool` value pointed by `failOver`, you have to *dereference` the pointer, i.e.

```
bool my_value = *failOver;
```

So, I don't know how `mmap` works, but if it returns a `void*`, you may want to cast that to `bool*` and then to *dereference* it. Furthermore, I think you don't want to read `sizeof(failOver)` bytes (i.e. `sizeof(bool*)` bytes), but `sizeof(bool)` bytes.

2- You have to define your variable (i.e. making room for it in memory) if you want it to be found by another translation unit. To define it, you have to initialize it *in the global scope*:

```
bool* failOver = 0;
```

Then, in the other file you can declare it `extern` and use it.

Comment: @MamasLiebling Tell me what you can't understand and I'll try to make it clearer.

Comment: 1. I have to do the static_cast, because the mmap does return an void and c++ doesnt cast implicit.  2. right, i dont want it, but the compiler is complaining      
3. i added and failOver=false in the main, now its declared and initializied, or am i false?

Comment: @MamasLiebling `failOver = false;` in main neither declares nor initialises `failOver`. Get rid of it. Show us the code you are actually having trouble with (in function.cpp) instead of the code that is correct (in main.cpp)

Comment: What are you actually trying to do? It looks to me like you are trying to create shared memory to hold a single bool! Why on earth would you want to do that? Just use a global variable.

Comment: @john i need to modify the variable in an function which is forked in the main. i cant compile it, at the moment iam only trying to echo it. which is not working because it cant access it

Comment: @MamasLiebling Forked? As in the Unix fork function?

Comment: @john correct. the function connects to an host, if this is not working it tries at the second host, if this worked, it should modify the failOver. the next fork will then connect directly to second host. The global variable is not working because it is an copy in the fork and does not modify the mother variable.

Comment: @MamasLiebling Edited my answer